# Some in Ramda.js

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I'm trying to do a something like .some in js, but with ramda.js. And I can't understand how.
I have an array of objects, and I want to get a true/false if some of object has value property with array.length > 1.

```
const features = [
{
    name: "First name",
    type: "First type",
    value: ["First value 1", "First value 2"],
},
{
    name: "Second name",
    type: "Second type",
    value: ["Second value 1"],
}
];
```

In vanilla.js it can be like:

```
features.some((f) => f.value.length > 1)
```

But I want to do it with Ramda. And try this, but it is not work:

```
const isHasSomeValues = R.gt(R.length(R.prop('value')), 1);
console.log(R.any(isHasSomeValues)(features))
```

Comment: I think you're looking for [`R.any`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#any).

Answer (score 3):

- [`R.any`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#any) is the Ramda equivalent for [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

I'd probably approach this like *is the prop value not empty?*,
as you are not really interested in how many items the value contains...
`gt 0` is enough.

```js
const isValueEmpty = R.propSatisfies(R.isEmpty, 'value');

const fn = R.any(
  R.complement(isValueEmpty),
);

const data = [
  {
    name: 'First name',
    type: 'First type',
    value: ['First value 1', 'First value 2'],
  },
  {
    name: 'Second name',
    type: 'Second type',
    value: ['Second value 1'],
  },
];

console.log(
  fn(data),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-3sdB9mAxNh2MIo6YkY05uY1qjkywAlDfCf5u1cSotv6k9CZUSyHVf4BJSpTYgla+YHLaHG8LUpqV7MHctlYzlw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

R.any excepts a predicate function, and `isHasSomeValues` is actually a `false` value:

```js
const isHasSomeValues = R.gt(R.length(R.prop('value')), 1);

console.log(isHasSomeValues);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-3sdB9mAxNh2MIo6YkY05uY1qjkywAlDfCf5u1cSotv6k9CZUSyHVf4BJSpTYgla+YHLaHG8LUpqV7MHctlYzlw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

To create a function that is a combination of multiple functions you can use R.pipe or R.compose to perform a set of actions, where each action receives the result of the previous one. The first action (function) in the pipeline is called with the values passed into the pipe - an object in your case.

```js
const { pipe, any, prop, length, gt, __ } = R

const fn = any(pipe(
  prop('value'), // get the value array
  length, // get the length
  gt(__, 0), // check if the length is greater than 0
))

const features = [{"name":"First name","type":"First type","value":["First value 1","First value 2"]},{"name":"Second name","type":"Second type","value":["Second value 1"]}]

const result = fn(features)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-3sdB9mAxNh2MIo6YkY05uY1qjkywAlDfCf5u1cSotv6k9CZUSyHVf4BJSpTYgla+YHLaHG8LUpqV7MHctlYzlw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

There are other ways to combine functions in Ramda, one of them is currying. All of Ramda's functions are [curried](https://itnext.io/a-beginners-guide-to-ramda-part-1-7e4a34972e97), and all of them has a fixed arity (the number of parameters the function accepts). This means that if pass a single parameter to a function that requires 2, you'll get back a partially applied function. Only when you'll supply a 2nd parameter, the function would return the result.

In this case, R.any has an arity of 2. I pass it the predicate (`pipe(...)`), and get a new function. Only when I supply the 2nd value (the array), I get the result.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! It's really hard for me to change approach with functional programming.

Comment: You're welcome. You should also try @Hitmans answer.